# Why is it a mistake to capture the forked rook?

Tags: analysis, strategy, tactics, evaluation

In a recent game, I forked a queen and rook with a knight. After seeing no immediate threats from 8. Qf4 I immediately captured with 8. ...Nxb3. Apparently this was quite a mistake (a 213 centipawn evaluation drop), but it's not clear to me why the material advantage from Nxb3 is inferior to Stockfish's recommendation of Nxc2, let alone *far* superior.

```
[White "White"]
[Black "Black"]

[fen ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Bc4 { B20 Sicilian Defense: Bowdler Attack } b6 3. a4 Bb7 4. Qf3 e6 5. Ra3? { (-0.77 → -2.15) Mistake. d3 was best. } a6 6. Rb3 Nc6 7. Nh3? { (-2.78 → -5.30) Mistake. Re3 was best. } Nd4 8. Qf4 Nxb3? { (-5.02 → -2.89) Mistake. Nxc2 was best. } 9. Ng5?? { (-2.89 → -6.87) Blunder. Bxb3 was best. } f6 10. Nxe6 dxe6 11. Bxe6?! { (-5.59 → -10.58) Inaccuracy. Bxb3 was best. } Nd4 12. Bg4 Nxc2+ 0-1
```

What am I missing here? Why shouldn't Nxb3 be played (or maybe, why is Nxc2 far superior)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key point is that taking the rook reduces your positional advantage.

- Your knight is active but the rook is passive;
- With your knight on `d4` the squares the rook can move to are extremely limited. After `8. ... Nxc2+ 9. Kf1 h6`, only `f3` and `g3` are better squares for the rook. However, with the advancement of pawns on the king side, the queen will be chased away and the development of `Nf6` will trap the rook. This will gain both the material advantage and the increasing positional advantage.

This is reflected in the Stockfish evaluation as `Nxb3` yields -2.3, with the -2 coming from the material whereas `Nxc2+` yields -3.8.

Comment: Wouldn't Nxb3 also prevent white from castling?

Answer (score 4):

Note, also, that Nxc2 is +1 on material while Nxb3 is +2 as the knight should be captured--I do not see why your opponent launched that futile attack and let the knight escape.

However, along with that +1 material the king has to move, costing him several moves to get the rook out and the king to safety.

Answer (score 1):

A 213 "centipawn" loss can be critical in an equal position. If you still have a +9 position, it's irrelevant. In this case, I think the engine dislikes to take the rook right now because 8...b5 looks like a stronger move. If White removes the bishop, you can still take the rook, while 9.axb5 axb5 would make your ...Ra1 threat unstoppable